# know svn committer client ip

Tags: svn

Is it possible to know from which client ip a commit is made in an svn repository? It will be helpful for statistics since we can work from different sites within the same big network.
(UPDATE): my committers are using SSH to push changes to the repository

Comment: That depends. How do your clients connect to the svn server? Is it through Apache, or svnserve, or something else?

Comment: Can you try this hook: [Subversion: Get ip-address of user in pre-commit hook?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529976/subversion-get-ip-address-of-user-in-pre-commit-hook