# Who pushed commits into remote repository?

Tags: git

Assume we have two people which are working on one repository:

```
$ git config --global user.name "john"
$ git config --global user.email john@example.com
```

His login to remote repository: john.

```
$ git config --global user.name "emma"
$ git config --global user.email emma@example.com
```

Her login to remote repository: emma.

Assume John is start behaving like a bad boy and he run these commands

```
$ git config --global user.name "emma"
$ git config --global user.email emma@example.com
```

and commit some nasty code :P

Is there a way to conclude who pushed commits with nasty code into remote repository?

Comment: Look at the `.bash_history` (linux) and manually check?

Answer (score 1):

This information is not stored by git, and you will have to write a receive hook (eg, pre-receive) and log it separately in a log file that you will maintain.

Jonas Wielicki has mentioned that **gitolite** is the more appropriate solution, and if you can run it that would be advantageous - you'll get the audit trail out of the box. The IP information would be located in `.gitolite/logs`.

Otherwise, back to receive hooks:

> The first script to run when handling a push from a client is
>   pre-receive. It takes a list of references that are being pushed from
>   stdin; if it exits non-zero, none of them are accepted. You can use
>   this hook to do things like make sure none of the updated references
>   are non-fast-forwards; or to check that the user doing the pushing has
>   create, delete, or push access or access to push updates to all the
>   files they’re modifying with the push.
>   http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Here's how you could grab the IP address: [Subversion: Get ip-address of user in pre-commit hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529976/subversion-get-ip-address-of-user-in-pre-commit-hook). Yes it's for SVN but you could re-use the perl code referenced in the answers.

**EDIT.** [`git notes`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html) to the rescue - no need to maintain an external log file.

Here's an example of what you could do. I'll simulate the client IP for illustration purposes:

```
---- .git/hooks/pre-receive ---
#!/bin/sh

# When the connection is over SSH you can possibly
# obtain the IP with $SSH_CLIENT or $SSH_CONNECTION
# otherwise use netstat or lsof
#
CLIENT_IP="127.0.0.1"

echo Your IP is logged as : $CLIENT_IP

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
  git notes append -m "Commit $newrev forwarded from $oldrev by source: ${CLIENT_IP} at: $(date)" $newrev
done
```

Comment: Hint: gitolite, which seems to be very widespread these days, already maintains a log.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Yes, that would be the more standard way to approach this. Let me add this to the answer.

Comment: Gitolite aside, [Gerrit Code Review](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) has ACL support for deciding who gets to impersonate other users.

Comment: @MagnusBäck That's good to know, I had very superficial experiences with gerrit. Not sure if the OP uses it - he'll need to clarify in the question tags ...