# SVN: Would like to see the computer each commit came from when looking at the logs

Tags: svn, logging, commit

I'm using different SVN clients on Windows (Tortoise), Linux (NetBeans) and Mac (SmartSVN).

I'd like to know if it is possible to configure the SVN server (or the clients) so it keeps (or know) the computer (e.g. IP address) that is at the origin of every commit?

Answer (score 0):

How about just using slightly different versions of your name when you commit? E.g. using `Bart@Windows`, `Bart@Linux` and `Bart@Mac` will solve your problem in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
svn propset --revprop svn:log -r REV
```

docs avaliable at: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html

This command can be used to set any information in the log and you should do this on post-commit hook. Problem is, post commit hook doesn't know the client IP address. Some info on how to get it can be found here: [Subversion: Get ip-address of user in pre-commit hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529976/subversion-get-ip-address-of-user-in-pre-commit-hook) and here http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2010-07/0480.shtml